# A very unique chess puzzle

Tags: chess

Find a legal move for white that does NOT mate in one.
[image: White to move]

Source: by Karl Fabel & was reprinted in Martin Gardner's New Mathematical Diversions from Scientific American (pub. Simon & Schuster), ch.19, p.223

Comment: I like to accept >12-18 hours after posting, because then you get attention to your puzzle but don't forget about the accepting altogether

Comment: It would be nice to add the proper reference for this puzzle, which was invented by puzzle master Sam Loyd.

Comment: @Yrodro It would indeed be nice to add the proper reference. I regret that I don't have it (the problem appears to not be in PDB or YACPDB), but I can say that it's by Karl Fabel & was reprinted in Martin Gardner's New Mathematical Diversions from Scientific American (pub. Simon & Schuster), ch.19, p.223.

Comment: have you looked at the solution?

Comment: This is *not* a unique puzzle!

Comment: @TheGreatDuck how, exactly?

Comment: @RosieF thanks for the source, I added it!

Comment: @thecoder16 you didn't create the password. Therefore, it is not unique.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck I think you misunderstand the definition of unique. I never said I created it. I just thought it was an unique puzzle.

Comment: @thecoder16 I know that. My definition of unique is that there is only one in existence. It was mostly a *joke*. You took it far too seriously. :p

Comment: @TheGreatDuck well yeah, hehe https://cdn.someecards.com/someecards/usercards/1339697486028_3996655.png

Comment: @thecoder16 sarcasm is a bad choice of words there. I was mostly making an ironic joke about your title and the need for a reference.

Comment: Quite confused now.

Comment: Is there a way to rule out / be sure of the board orientation? How can one be sure that the white pawns attack northwards?

Comment: @AlfieJ.Palmer because I say so :) admittedly, i should've included rank and file labels in the picture.

Comment: Now also on Chess Stack Exchange: [Uniquely Satisfying Puzzle](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/27130/7297)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I've found the actual answer:

> 1. Rc6

Then:

> 1... Rxh7

Because:

> The rook isn't pinned any more

Picture:

> [image: Unforced checkmate]

Comment: Nice puzzle, by the way. Had me fooled for a bit.

Comment: You could extend this puzzle to "White to play and stalemate", with 2. Rxc5+ Rb7 3. Kf8 1/2-1/2

Answer (score 14):

Another commonly seen solution to this sort of problem:

> White can legally resign.

Comment: also not the intended answer, but true, i guess :) I think they need to make a meta post about chess loopholes now! xD

Comment: The puzzle explicitly asks for a legal move. Resignation isn't a move.

Comment: There's an unwritten convention that players can't resign or agree a draw. That would just break so many problems. If you have commonly seen it, then please show me an example: I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the trick is, as with so many chess puzzles, that:

> we are looking at the board the wrong way.

In this case, there are several possible moves:

> Actually, I think there's no move that can force mate, if this is the case, because now the pawns are 'blocking' the wrong squares.

Comment: nice try, but this is not the case for this puzzle. the rank on the bottom is indeed the first rank.

Comment: It's true that sometimes the board is upside down. That is probably the most common unofficial joke. But you need to exhaust other options first. (The official joke, enshrined in the legendary Codex of Chess Problem Conventions, is that it may be the unexpected side to move, if you can prove that the expected side couldn't have moved last.)